# How is IFS really rendered?

Tags: bash

I've read bash manpage and other docs, but I find the explanation a bit confusing.

I have the following simple script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=""

echo $2

var=A B C

echo $var
```

if I execute it, eg:

```
LANG=C ./args2 3 4
4
./args2: line 7: B: command not found
```

I really don't understand, why $2 = 4? If manual says:

> If the value of IFS   is null, no word splitting occurs.

The same thing with var declaration, why it complains about "B"? So there is word splitting anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section of the bash manual lays out the steps: [Shell Operation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Operation)

In step 3, the script is broken up into commands, arguments, etc.

- in this step, we get the tokens "var=A", "B" and "C"
- see section [Simple Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Commands) where it says (emphasis mine):

> A simple command is [...] just a sequence of words separated by **blanks** 
>   
>   Word splitting is not performed until expansions, step 4.

As Qudit explained, *your* shell split "LANG=C ./args2 3 4" into tokens *before* launching the command "./args2"

Answer (score 1):

Before your script runs, IFS has its default value.  The argument splitting is done in the bash instance in which you ran your script and it splits things normally because you haven't set IFS yet.

Comment: If I run on the very shell: `export IFS=""; var=A B C
bash: B: no se encontró la orden`. It does the same thing. Why?